# How to upload php files required for a mysql db to control an Android app

Tags: android, mysql

I am developing a small android app, and the server side is developing on php. I have a wordpress hosting account with MYSQL,and a filemanager. I've created a database on it, Now I want to know how can I connect my php files with this mysql database. I didn't see an option to upload php files in mysql database.
WHERE SHOULD I UPLOAD THE PHP SCRIPTS THAT I HAD CREATED FOR THIS DATABASE?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. One time you ask 'where', the other time 'how'.

Comment: Further this seems to be not a programming question.

Comment: I'd suggest the wordpress tag

Answer (score 0):

The PHP scripts should be uploaded via the file manager to your web server. Usually it's under a directory named `public_html`. The PHP scripts do not belong in the MySQL database itself.